# Problem with flutter Http on the get parameters

Tags: flutter

I have a problem with flutter htpp, i'm a beginner but i don't understand why the link of the http give me some problems what i do with this problem?

[image]

Comment: as the error says, you need Uri object not String object, so you need to do this: `Uri.parse('https://httpbin.org/get')`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a URI to the `http.get` method but you currently give it a string.

Just wrap the link inside a  `URI.parse('yourLink')`